# Sonatype Nexus OSS 3 - Enable Upload Snapshot

Tags: repository, maven-3, nexus3

How can I enable Nexus to make upload of SNAPSHOT version jar? On "server configuration and administration" tab I can see maven-snapshots repository but I can't see on Upload tab.

[image: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager]

**PS: I'm logged in as admin user**

Comment: Please check https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/user-interface/uploading-components Usually uploading SNAPSHOT's via UI does not make sense......

Comment: How make sense to upload a SNAPSHOT? @khmarbaise

Comment: Usually via Maven/Gradle...etc...